# Configuration file change - Should mobile app poll or is there a way to push/notify client?

Tags: android, notifications, push

I have developed an Android mobile app that uses the information stored in a configuration file to upload files. This configuration file initially resides on a server and the mobile app upon it's first use will download this file from the server.

Now subsequently what may happen is that the configuration file (a JSON file) at the server side will change. So what will be the best way to address this? Should the client mobile app keep polling the server and detect any change in size / date modified or is there a more efficient way that I can easily push some message or notification to the client from the server and then the client will download the updated configuration file. I am not a fan of polling. Moreover regular polling will increase the data usage, and even though it may not be much, it actually matters in few situations where data plan is very limited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing a message notifying clients that a new config is available is a better solution in terms of scalability, device battery impact and network efficiency (just remember to avoid having all clients downloading the new config at the same time).

[Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is an ideal solution if you're working with Android only. It is effectively free and runs on Google's infrastructure. If the config is small enough (<4kb) you can even send it directly to devices using GCM instead of downloading it from your server.

However, implementing push notifications is slightly more complicated than simple polling. If (like the vast majority of apps out there) your app only has a handful of users, you may want to start off with a simple polling mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear and concise explanation. GCM was on my mind but again like you mentioned it's a bit harder to 'implement correctly'. Anyways I think I will go with GCM. I never liked polling - except for this one reason: as polling keeps looking up things, if it fails once, it may succeed the next time whereas systems where you just broadcast things, there is some slight change that something never arrives. I guess there can be some mechanism for acknowledgement too and I'll figure that you. Anyway thanks once again